# Get current date as epoch from datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a date (start of day) as epoch from datetime. Issue, I think, is the object gets turned to a `date` object with the code below

```
from datetime import datetime

today_epoch = datetime.timestamp(datetime.utcnow().date())
```

This throws
`TypeError: descriptor 'timestamp' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'datetime.date' object`

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

epoch_time = int(time.time())
print(epoch_time)
```

And if you insist to use `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

epoch_time = datetime.now().timestamp()
print(epoch_time)
```

To get rid of decimals, convert to int:
`print(int(epoch_time))`

Comment: thanks but this seems to just give the time currently and not just the date, ie at 0h 0s

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

today_epoch = datetime.timestamp(datetime.utcnow())
today_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(today_epoch).date()
```

Comment: thanks but that still seems to return a date object and not an epoch value?